# AC DC adapter sawtooth current draw above rated value

Tags: power, current, adapter, sawtooth-waveform

I will be using AC DC wall adapter to power the flyback converter. Power adapter is rated 15V@3A = 45W.
The question is, can I draw peaks over 3A if I stay below 45W on average?

For example, with the following DCM sawtooth primary current draw, let's say I<sub>pk</sub> = 6A.

[image]

There are regions where no current is drawn, less than 3A is drawn, and more than 3A is drawn. For simplicity, let's say on average flyback draws only 30W of power.

1. Will adapter be able to supply 6A peaks in this setup if I stay below rated power? Will this cause voltage sag during peaks? Does this depend on any current protection circuitry in the adapter?
2. Is there a smart way to solve this? What if I slap a large input cap to allow it recharge when less than 3A is drawn and supply the excess current when more than 3A is drawn, would this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Your mandatory input filter will filter those peaks out.

Comment: Thanks @winny, indeed I overlooked SMPS input filter. Most designs seem to use a simple capacitor. Do you think it makes sense to go for LC or not?

Comment: Simulate it and learn from the experience!

Comment: Simulation shows that without LC filter damping the supply voltage can spike. Perhaps inductance in series with a supply is not the best idea.

Comment: Depends. You need to dimension it appropriately. Do a step response!

Answer (score 2):

If a power supply has a rated output current of 3A, this means that it can supply 3A output current **continuously**. However, this specification does not tell us if it's able to provide >3A peaks. There may be voltage sag, or even lockout due to sudden overload. Who knows? The datasheet, if any, can give info about peak output power capability in terms of output power and duration (e.g. 60W for 1 second). Without having this info, we can't (and shouldn't) do any estimations as it will be unscientific and unreliable/untrustable. This answers your 1st question.

> What if I slap a large input cap to allow it recharge when less than 3A is drawn and supply the excess current when more than 3A is drawn, would this work?

This is completely a different story. We don't know the design of the aforementioned adapter, so we don't know if placing large capacitors across its output would work or not. Increasing the output capacitance of an adapter is not always a good way as it changes the behaviour to step load changes (i.e. 0 to 100 percent loading or vice versa) of the adapter. This means that placing large capacitors **may** lead the adapter to get unstable. Who knows?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a fully documented AC/DC adapter that specifies max output capacitance (load capacitance) that can be driven. This is not available from a dollar-store/Aliexpress/Amazon. You'll need to get a Meanwell or a CUI or other reputable brand power supply from a reputable distributor. Likely $20 or more each.

Or, you can simply try your existing setup and make sure it doesn't oscillate and/or overheat while it maintains voltage control.